# Proxy settings for a single website

Tags: unity, kde, proxy

in KDE i can set manual proxies and in exception use particular site like youtube here shown in screenshot use that proxies only and all other sites load normally, my question is how can i do that in unity or gnome, so that only youtube can use these proxies?

[image]

Comment: why would you want to do such a thing! Can you elaborate the reasons behind doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Proxy Settings for a single website

As you want to set proxy for a single website, there is no point to mess with system proxy. And to change system proxy again and again will be a tedious job also. What you want could be achieved with Google Chrome very easily. I can recommend you an extension in chrome "Proxy SwitchySharp". **It will enable you to switch between two or more proxy settings and direct connections with just one click.**

[image]

Besides that it has many other advanced options to play with your proxies for example you can set switching rules, you can take backup of your settings etc.

[image]

**How to install Proxy SwitchySharp in Google Chrome**,

- open google-chrome
- Go to Settings >> Extensions (or just enter in address bar `chrome://extensions/`)
- click on "Get more extensions" (left-bottom)
- search for "Proxy SwitchySharp"

[image]

- click on `+` sign to add.

**Some Clarifications**

- It can be used independent of desktop environments like KDE, Gnome, Unity etc. As it uses its own proxy settings on browser, not your system proxy.
- It can use proxy configured by tor or any other sources.

**What you need to do**

- Create two profiles in Proxy SwitchySharp, say profile_1 and profile_2.
- profile_1 will have your default proxy or direct connection and profile_2 with tor generated proxy and respective port.
- When you are surfing sites without restriction use profile_1 and use profile_2 for restricted sites.

Hope this is what you asked.

Comment: let us know if you have any query?

Comment: thanks for your answer. i tested it, it works but still i would love to see if there is any kde like solution without using extensions in chrome and firefox. if there isn't i would accept your answer. also if you can answer i created multiple rules, is it possible to enter multiple sites in single rule.

Comment: can you also suggest something for firefox, i am using foxyproxy but it doesn't have protocols in it just socks settings

Comment: @wedu yes it is possible to enter multiple sites in single rule. If you surf youtube with your modified proxy you can access all other sites too. But you can not use two profiles simultaneously. You should not need it as you can change profiles in a single click.

Comment: @wedu I do not know any add-on for firefox as efficient as proxy switchysharp

Comment: @wedu you can take a look at it [for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/proxy-selector/). I never used it.

Comment: thanks man for your help, i preferred foxyproxy for firefox and chrome over switchysharp and your answer is accepted because i now can also use this in windows 7. foxyproxy has option of adding site with quick add option which are also blocked in particular country. quite fed up with this blocking of domains but thanks to the people who made tor, switchysharp or foxyproxy so that we can access the sites.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you make a system wide proxy, just for 2 or 3 websites? I mean it is more simple, and in my opinion better to make a proxy for those websites in Firefox or chrome or whatever browser you use.
 Just think about it, every time you use Skype or steam or any other program that needs internet, you will have to see if you are accessing YouTube or google or whatever other site you want to use proxy.

I think another solution would be to install an extension in Chrome or Firefox and configure the browser only to use the proxy for those specific websites.

Comment: youtube is blocked in my country unfortunately, so when i visit some blogs, news stories etc having youtube videos embedded i have to run network and apply system wide proxies, in kde i liked this approach. and i will love to use tor instead of some random proxies.

Comment: if i want to do it in a browser how can i do it, chrome uses gnome network settings. i could not find extension for doing this job, could you please give me one and does it chain to tor?

Answer (score 1):

I still think [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/410846/127327) is a better solution for your problem. If you insist to change system proxy for your purpose you can use the shell script given below. And you want this on unity or gnome according to your question.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
    echo "$0: missing operand"
    echo "Usage $0 [option]"
    echo "options : [default|restricted]"
    exit 0
fi
case "$1" in
    default)
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled true
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host 'proxy.server.addr_1'
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port proxy_port_1
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-user 'user_id'
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-password 'password'
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy use-same-proxy true
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts ['localhost',  '127.0.0.1', 'all', 'other', 'hosts']
        ;;
    restricted)
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled true
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host 'proxy.server.addr_2'
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port proxy_port_2
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-user 'user_id'
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-password 'password'
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy use-same-proxy true
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts ['localhost',  '127.0.0.1', 'all', 'other', 'hosts']
        ;;
    * ) 
        echo "$0: invalid option"
        ;;
esac
```

You need to define two sets of `proxy.server.addr`, `proxy_port`, `user_id`, `password` and `ignored hosts` in above two sections for your dafault and tor created proxy respectively.

If you do not want any part just remove that line or modify options according to your need. For example if you do not have `user_id` and `password` for your proxy remove those lines when you copy the script. Most probably tor does not provide user name and password.

**Usage**

save the script as `switch_proxy.sh`. Give it execution permission.

```
chmod +x /path/to/switch_proxy.sh
```

To use your default proxy system wide,

```
/path/to/switch_proxy.sh default
```

To use your modified proxy system wide,

```
/path/to/switch_proxy.sh restricted
```

Comment: thanks again, but this i think is same as setting alias pxm='gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'' in ~/.bash_aliases with all the proxy settings configured in gnome network manual settings.

Comment: @wedu you can create alias, bash function or put the script in your path to execute easily.